# Confirm logic for enum abstract method implementation and static class method what if they return instances of other objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, singleton, abstract

I'm a bit confused about methods implemented in an enum. Are they the same as static methods of a particular class? In otherwords they can not be associated with a particular instance? But then the different enumeration fields in the enum definition seem to be the particular instances. So there are multiple instances around arent there? Please help me demystify this concept. What if each of the method implementations of the enumerations return instances of other objects?  Sorry I know I may have asked a lot here, but I'm trying to understand the basis behind the method being defined as an abstract method in the enum to be used for polymorphism in the singleton sense (wow thats a mouthful)..

THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, Enum act as a class (internally it extend Object class). We can define attributes (fields) and methods in enum. Enum methods are instance method. If you are writing static keyword in method then only they become status methods. Not the fields, But the values of enum acts as instance of that enum. As, its method concept is same as class method, so you can return instance of any class in enum method which act as instance method of enum. You can't define abstract method in enum as it is not an abstract class. Enum are designed to provide single instance, As in Java 6 you can use enum as singletone.

```
public enum Animal{
    TIGER, LION
}
```

In this example, we will have total two instance (TIGER, LION) of Animal class. You can't create more instance of Enum outside.